# Dataframe Alternating Array

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I currently have an excel file with information like this:

```
Company Initial     Purchase Number
ABCD            A123456789
ABCD            B123456789
BCDE            C123456789
BCDE            D123456789
BCDE            E123456789
CDEF            F123456789
DEFG            G123456789
DEFG            H123456789
DEFG            I123456789
DEFG            J123456789
DEFG            K123456789
```

And I would like to turn it into a table such that the same company initial is not repeated consecutively.

```
Company Initial     Purchase Number
DEFG            K123456789
ABCD            A123456789
DEFG            G123456789
ABCD            B123456789
DEFG            J123456789
BCDE            C123456789
DEFG            I123456789
BCDE            D123456789
DEFG            H123456789
BCDE            E123456789
CDEF            F123456789
```

I am currently trying this in both Pandas and VBA but cannot seem to wrap my head around a viable solution. I am open to other Python libraries too.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there another parameter that determines the specific order (say date ofpurchase) or can it be any order as long as company initial never repeats the same name twice?

Comment: It can be in any order as long as the initials do not repeat

Comment: @molnay, you received several answers to your question - it would be helpful for other users to identify a helpful answer by your acceptance (or upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another possiblity with the help of ListBoxes in memory:

```
Sub Reshuffle()
Dim Arr As Variant, FreqArr As Variant, Place As Long, Comp1 As Variant, Comp2 As Variant
Dim rngArr As Range, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ListB1 As MSForms.ListBox, ListB2 As MSForms.ListBox

Set ListB1 = CreateObject("New:{8BD21D20-EC42-11CE-9E0D-00AA006002F3}")
Set ListB2 = CreateObject("New:{8BD21D20-EC42-11CE-9E0D-00AA006002F3}")

 Set rngArr = Range("A2:B12")

    With ListB1
        .Column = Application.Transpose(rngArr)
         ListB2.List = .List
                For i = LBound(.List) To UBound(.List)
                    Arr = Application.Match(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(.List, 0, 1)), Application.Index(.List, 0, 1), 0)
                    FreqArr = Application.Frequency(Arr, Arr)
                        If Application.Max(FreqArr) > (UBound(.List) + 2) / 2 Then MsgBox "not possible"
                            For j = 1 To UBound(.List) + 1
                                Place = Application.Match(Application.Large(FreqArr, j), FreqArr, 0)
                                Comp2 = .List(Place - 1, 0)
                                    If Comp2 <> Comp1 Then Exit For
                            Next j
                                Comp1 = Comp2
                                    With ListB2
                                        For k = LBound(.List, 2) To UBound(.List, 2)
                                            .List(i, k) = ListB1.List(Place - 1, k)
                                        Next k
                                        ListB1.RemoveItem Place - 1
                                    End With
                Next i
      End With
rngArr.Value = ListB2.List 'replaces in same range

Set ListB1 = Nothing
Set ListB2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice and interesting approach to use the flexibility of listbox manipulations together with a frequency array +1 :-)  Side note: some comments could make code more readable

Answer (score 0):

There is not a guaranteed solution here; if there are 10 ABCD and 1 DEFG, it can't be done. With that in mind, there are some ways to approach it that aren't optimal, but will at least give it a fair chance.
In simple terms:

1. Create a list of lists, where subeach list contains one company only
2. Sort the master list after the number of entries in each sublist. Fewest last
3. Move the first entry from the first list to the target list
4. Move the first entry from the second list to the target list
5. Repeat from no 3

Answer (score 0):

It become something very clumsy but somehow working in limited testing. May try and see if it withstand extended testing

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub arrangeArray()
    Dim Arr As Variant, Rslt As Variant, Dict As Dictionary
    Dim MxCnt As Long, i As Long, j As Long, MxKey As String, Rw As Long
    Dim Ky As String, PosInArr As Long, ArrLen As Long, RwCnt As Long
    Dim temp1 As Variant, temp2 As Variant
    Set Dict = New Dictionary
    Arr = Range("A1:B12").Value
    ReDim Rslt(1 To UBound(Arr, 1), 1 To 2)
    ArrLen = UBound(Arr, 1)

     MxKey = ""
     MxCnt = 0
        'Company names taken as keys in a dictionary, values are incremented to number of occurrences
        For i = 1 To ArrLen
        Ky = Arr(i, 1)
            If Dict.Exists(Ky) Then
            Dict(Ky) = Dict(Ky) + 1
            Else
            Dict.Add Ky, 1
            End If

            If MxCnt < Dict(Ky) Then
            MxKey = Ky
            MxCnt = Dict(Ky)
            End If
        Next


        If ArrLen - MxCnt < MxCnt - 1 Then
        MsgBox " it is not possible to Arrange Array Since Total remaining Company names other than " & MxKey & " (occurs " & MxCnt & " times ) is only " & ArrLen - MxCnt & " less than " & MxCnt - 1
        Exit Sub
        End If

        'Dictionary taken to array Arr2 for bubble sort
        i = Dict.Count
        Dim arr2 As Variant
        ReDim arr2(1 To i, 1 To 2)
        For i = 1 To Dict.Count
            arr2(i, 1) = Dict.Keys(i - 1)
            arr2(i, 2) = Dict.Items(i - 1)
        Next i

        'Bubble sort Arr2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr2, 1) - 1
            For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr2, 1)
                If arr2(i, 2) < arr2(j, 2) Then
                    temp1 = arr2(j, 1)
                    temp2 = arr2(j, 2)
                    arr2(j, 1) = arr2(i, 1)
                    arr2(j, 2) = arr2(i, 2)
                    arr2(i, 1) = temp1
                    arr2(i, 2) = temp2
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        'First available position of the key in original array Arr
        For i = 1 To Dict.Count
        Ky = arr2(i, 1)
        arr2(i, 2) = 0
            For j = 1 To ArrLen
                If Arr(j, 1) = Ky Then
                arr2(i, 2) = j   'First available position of the key in Arr
                Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next i

'Create result array as populating it each company names as long available in original array
    Rw = 1
    Do
        RwCnt = 0
        For i = 1 To Dict.Count
        Ky = arr2(i, 1)
        PosInArr = arr2(i, 2)
            If PosInArr > 0 Then
            Rslt(Rw, 1) = Ky
            Rslt(Rw, 2) = Arr(PosInArr, 2)
            Rw = Rw + 1
            RwCnt = RwCnt + 1
            arr2(i, 2) = 0
                'Find Next available Ky in Arr
                    For j = PosInArr + 1 To ArrLen
                        If Arr(j, 1) = Ky Then
                        arr2(i, 2) = j     'next available position of the key in Arr
                        Exit For
                        End If
                     Next j

            If Rw > ArrLen Then Exit For  
            If RwCnt = 2 Then Exit For   ' exit to next Do loop after two rows
            End If
        Next i
    If Rw > ArrLen Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Range("D1").Resize(UBound(Rslt, 1), 2).Value = Rslt

    End Sub
```

Result is like

```
ABCD    A123456789      DEFG    G123456789
ABCD    B123456789      BCDE    C123456789
BCDE    C123456789      DEFG    H123456789
BCDE    D123456789      BCDE    D123456789
BCDE    E123456789      DEFG    I123456789
CDEF    F123456789      BCDE    E123456789
DEFG    G123456789      DEFG    J123456789
DEFG    H123456789      ABCD    A123456789
DEFG    I123456789      DEFG    K123456789
DEFG    J123456789      ABCD    B123456789
DEFG    K123456789      DEFG    K123456789
DEFG    K123456789      CDEF    F123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I have come up with a solution in Python using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

# Create dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(sys.argv[1] + "\\data\\Book1.xlsx")

# Get count and merge values
dfKeys = df["Company Initial"].value_counts().keys().to_list()                                  # Get list of names for each initial
dfValues = df["Company Initial"].value_counts().to_list()                                       # Get list of count for each initial

dfList = []
dfDict = {}

# Combining keys and values into list, creating dictionary for each initial
for i in range(0,len(dfKeys)):
    dfList.append([dfKeys[i], dfValues[i]])                                                     # Create list with initial and count
    dfDict[dfList[i][0]] = df[df["Company Initial"] == dfList[i][0]]                            # Dictionary for each initial

# New Dataframe
df = df[0:0]                                                                                    # Reset dataframe
initial = ""                                                                                    # Declare initial

# Shuffling
for x in range(0, len(dfList)):                                                                 # For every initial
    while dfList[x][1] > 0:                                                                     # While initial count is larger than 0

        # Failsafe: no more other initials with count remaining
        if all(item[1] == 0 for item in dfList[(x + 1):len(dfList)]):
            while dfList[x][1] > 0:                                                             # While initial count is larger than 0
                df = df.append(dfDict[dfList[x][0]][(dfList[x][1] - 1):dfList[x][1]])           # Add primary record
                dfList[x][1] = dfList[x][1] - 1                                                 # Reduce count by 1

        # Initials with count exist
        else:
            for i in range(x + 1,len(dfList)):                                                  # For every other carrier
                if dfList[x][1] == 0:
                    break
                elif dfList[i][1] > 0:
                    if initial != dfList[x][0]:                                                 # If previous carrier is not same as current carrier
                        df = df.append(dfDict[dfList[x][0]][(dfList[x][1] - 1):dfList[x][1]])   # Add primary record
                        dfList[x][1] = dfList[x][1] - 1                                         # Reduce count by 1
                    df = df.append(dfDict[dfList[i][0]][(dfList[i][1] - 1):dfList[i][1]])       # Add secondary record
                    dfList[i][1] = dfList[i][1] - 1                                             # Reduce count by 1
                    initial = df.iloc[len(df) - 1]["Company Initial"]

df = df.reset_index()                                                                           # Remove first row and reset index numbers
del df["index"]                                                                                 # Delete index column

print(df)
```

This creates the following dataframe:

```
   Company Initial Purchase Number
0             DEFG      K123456789
1             BCDE      E123456789
2             DEFG      J123456789
3             ABCD      B123456789
4             DEFG      I123456789
5             CDEF      F123456789
6             DEFG      H123456789
7             BCDE      D123456789
8             DEFG      G123456789
9             ABCD      A123456789
10            BCDE      C123456789
```